# What defines the "war-ness" of my project?

Tags: java, maven

I'm running the goal: `tomcat:deploy`. There are no errors, but it's not deploying my project into tomcat. I noticed this message:

```
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
```

What defines the "war-ness" of my project? How do I make my Eclipse project a war project?

Here's my plugin setting:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </plugin>
```

I have my structure like this:

```
src > main > java 
src > main > webapp > WEB-INF > web.xml
```

This one works with the `maven:war plugin`. I'm able to build a war with this structure.

My end objective is to do away with the war building part and be able to deploy my project to tomcat with one maven command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you are missing the 'packaging' element in your `pom.xml`:

```
     <packaging>war</packaging>
```

If you don't include one, the default packaging is 'jar'.